R DirichletMultinomial package - libgsl.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I'm having problems installing DirichletMultinomial R package. The main issue being, R does not recognize libgsl.so.27, which is in my /usr/local/lib directory:
$ ls -lh /usr/local/lib
total 46M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27M Apr 29 11:30 libgsl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.2M Apr 29 11:30 libgslcblas.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  948 Apr 29 11:30 libgslcblas.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 29 11:30 libgslcblas.so -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Apr 29 11:30 libgslcblas.so.0 -> libgslcblas.so.0.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.3M Apr 29 11:30 libgslcblas.so.0.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  917 Apr 29 11:30 libgsl.la*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 29 11:30 libgsl.so -> libgsl.so.27.0.0*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Apr 29 11:30 libgsl.so.27 -> libgsl.so.27.0.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  16M Apr 29 11:30 libgsl.so.27.0.0*
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   20 Apr 29 11:30 pkgconfig/

Whenever I try to install the package,I get this error:
gcc -shared -L/HL8/HApp/R/4.3.3/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o DirichletMultinomial.so R_init_DirichletMultinomial.o dirichlet_fit.o dirichlet_fit_main.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/HL8/HApp/R/4.3.3/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-DirichletMultinomial/00new/DirichletMultinomial/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DirichletMultinomial’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/nsk980613/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/00LOCK-DirichletMultinomial/00new/DirichletMultinomial/libs/DirichletMultinomial.so':
  libgsl.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed

As I said, I've downloaded gsl, both by using package manager (yum) and by manually installing using the tarball. I've currently erased the yum-installed gsl package as it did not work, and I fear I might break something if I uninstall my manual gsl installation.
I did try updating my LD_LIBRARY PATH:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
I've seen similar issues get solved with this, but for me this did not work. I really can't think of reasons as to why it's not working, but if there's one thing I should note is that I'm currently using R on a remote server. Downloading it on my local R worked fine.
Any help or recommendation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

What flavour Linux are you running on the remote server? I can see it's not Debian based.

The remote server uses rocky linux 8.9. Not too sure about the kernel but I believe it wasn't the latest version (can't really update it either unfortunately).

I don't have a Rocky Linux machine but here's what you need to install the library onto a Rocky Linux 8.9 Docker image.
FROM rockylinux:8.9

RUN dnf install -y epel-release
RUN dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
RUN dnf install -y R gsl-devel

RUN R -e 'install.packages("BiocManager", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")'
RUN R -e 'BiocManager::install("DirichletMultinomial", ask = FALSE)'
RUN R -e 'library(DirichletMultinomial)'

Have you followed these steps on your machine?
When I checked on the location of libgsl.so I found that it was in /usr/lib64 (not /usr/local/lib).
# find / -name libgsl.so
/usr/lib64/libgsl.so

If instead you install GSL from source then this is what you need to do:
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-2.7.1.tar.gz
cd gsl-2.7.1
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

Then confirm that all files are present:
find /usr/lib -name "libgsl*"

That should produce the following output (pretty much precisely!):
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libgsl.so.27
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so
/usr/lib/libgsl.so.27.0.0
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.a
/usr/lib/libgsl.a
/usr/lib/libgslcblas.so.0
/usr/lib/libgsl.la
/usr/lib/libgsl.so

Start R and install the required package.

I'm not using Docker atm, but as far as how I've downloaded dependencies I don't see anything different except for the packet manager. Will follow this if I have to use docker though, thanks!

No, you don't need to use Docker at all. What I wanted to illustrate was the process for installing on a pristine Rocky Linux 8.9 system, which is effectively what you get when you build this Docker image.

"I don't see anything different except for the packet manager." Can you elaborate? This might be important. Do you mean dnf or how I'm installing in R?

Oh I meant dnf. Now that I think about it I installed gsl after R so that part is different too. Afaik dnf is another package manager, do I need to install that as well?

Might be worth a try. Alternatively, please provide the commands that you used to install these dependencies.

When I tried yum I did sudo yum install gsl-devel then inside R: install.packages("BiocManager", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org") BiocManager::install("DirichletMultinomial") and when yum install didn't work I downloaded gsl tarball directly from the GNU website and installed by running the config file and the makefile, which installed gsl in the /usr/local/lib directory. as for the commands it was just ./configure > make > make install.

Okay, good. Please run find / -name libgsl.so and let me know what results you get.

Sorry for the delay. I got these two results:
/root/gsl-2.7.1/.libs/libgsl.so
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.so



I've added further content to the end of my answer addressing the case where you install from source.
